# Is it possible that Leap Motion Controller will work with Ubuntu?

Tags: hardware

I skimmed through https://forums.leapmotion.com/forumdisplay.php?7-Linux and didn't find any precise answer. Is there one?

Does it use closed data format? Does it prohibit reverse engineering in some EULA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At this time, our focus is on Windows and OS X, with Linux being on our agenda. 
>   leapmotion_mist

It seems it is on their agenda, but is not in production yet. There most likely will be a hacked version of support before the official support comes out.  There was also some talk about using an Anduro to capture the signals and use that as a go-between.

Hope this helps.